# Performing a "log in to steam" in a website

Tags: node.js, post, request, openid, steam

I want to perform a login to steam via cs go lounge.

The process of logging in manually is : 
1. Pressing the login button redirects to [steam website](https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fcsgolounge.com%2Flogin&openid.realm=https%3A%2F%2Fcsgolounge.com&openid.ns.sreg=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fextensions%2Fsreg%2F1.1&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select).
2.Fill out the username and password.

3.If there is email authentication you need to input a special code that you receive. 

4.It returns to the website with a special cookie of a token.

Now i want to know how can i do the same through node.js ? I want to some access cs go lounge data but it's only available if you are logged in.

I have tried sending a form with my username and password, but i don't understand the response that i'm getting :

```
var request = require('request');

var myJSONObject = {
    "username" : "username",
    "password" : "password",
};

request({
url: "https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fcsgolounge.com%2Flogin&openid.realm=https%3A%2F%2Fcsgolounge.com&openid.ns.sreg=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fextensions%2Fsreg%2F1.1&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select",
    method: "POST",
    json: true,  
    body: myJSONObject
    }, function (error, response, body){
    console.log(response);
});
```

My response looks like :

```
{ _readableState: 
{ objectMode: false,
 highWaterMark: 16384,
 buffer: [],
 length: 0,
 pipes: null,
 pipesCount: 0,
 flowing: true,
 ended: true,
```

I saw at the steam page that all the field are in a form (i know how to send a POST from with json object ) but i don't know what field to send , and how to handle the two steps login(first username and password and then email code).
And it goes on and on..

I also tried logging in from chrome and extracting the cookie and using in the website , but again without luck

```
var requestify = require('requestify');
var cheerio = require("cheerio");

requestify.get('http://csgolounge.com/trade?t=99441462', {
    cookies: {

        "domain": "csgolounge.com",
        "expirationDate": 1443870461.091163,
        "hostOnly": true,
        "httpOnly": false,
        "name": "token",
        "path": "/",
        "secure": false,
        "session": false,
        "storeId": "0",
        "value": "0be791e29ba5bd1d839cb4c69bca5ba4",
        "id": 8
}
})
  .then(function(response) {    
      var $ = cheerio.load(response.getBody());
      console.log($(".buttonright").attr('href'));
  }
);
```

Honestly i'm out of ideas , except manually touching each button with jquery.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you login to csgolounge, check Google Chrome's network data (F12 -> Network). Find the line where it loads the page itself and check what Cookies are sent in request headers. You tried to send wrong cookies in your example. You need to send "id" and "token" fields with cookies header in order to access csgolounge.